# TextSuggest Universal Autocomplete Installation Error

Tags: software-installation, compiling, auto-completion

I followed the instructions to install the autocomplete tool [TextSuggest](https://gitlab.com/bharadwaj-raju/TextSuggest)  but now I'm stuck at this part:

> Run the command textsuggest-server in the background, and set it to
>   run on startup.
>
> Set the command textsuggest to a keyboard shortcut.
>   Type a word, select it, press the shortcut and TextSuggest will give
>   you autocomplete.

After running the command in the terminal this error comes up:

```
doit@tox:~$ textsuggest-server
textsuggest-server: command not found
```

Same error if I run it in the CD of textsuggest.
Also I got this error after the installation:

```
/usr/include/dbus-c++-1/dbus-c++/dispatcher.h:249:13: note: conversion of argument 3 would be ill-formed
Makefile:416: recipe for target 'textsuggest-ui.o' failed
make: *** [textsuggest-ui.o] Error 1
```

How to get it to work? I'm using `gcc (Ubuntu 7.2.0-8ubuntu3.2) 7.2.0`.

Comment: which version of Ubuntu are you running?

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 17.10

Comment: This is a bug in the source code of TextSuggest (that likely only becomes apparent due to different default settings in newer GCC releases). Please file a bug report with the developers/maintainers of TextSuggest. I'd vote to close but that doesn't work on questions with open bounties.